# transfer twilio flex live call to another number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to transfer incoming live call in twilio flex to another number that is not in twilio. Couldn't find any documentation regarding this topic.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249790/twilio-how-to-transfer-a-in-progress-call-to-another-number, have a look at this question I think this is achievable using Twilio Conference.